# SQL Server 2012 connection issues in Visual Studio 2012 Server Explorer

Tags: networking, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, remote-connection

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2012 installed on Windows Server 2012 through Visual Studio 2012 but keep getting an error 25 connection string is not valid message when trying to connect through server explorer.

As far as I am aware it is sharing the same IP address as the main server. I am not connected to the domain but have checked that remote connections are enabled and port 1433. I can also connect to the main server.

I am new to SQL Server so any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must have the correct connection string. I show the codes in C# :

```
string con = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='c:\users\pc\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection concect = new SqlConnection(con);
```

The data connection string is located in `yourdatabase.mdf` file in connection string. you will see that in visual studio.

Update :

in server explorer right click on dataconnections then choose add connection. then select Microsoft SQL Server in server name use "." for your server name. then you can select your database or you can attach your database file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I’m not up to the coding part yet and am just trying to connect through server explorer.

Comment: Thanks again but I am just wanting to connect to the remote server for making SQL queries etc. I don’t really have a specific database to work on or anything.