# SQL Server 2012 connection issues in Visual Studio 2012 Server Explorer

Tags: networking, windows-8, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2012 installed on Windows Server 2012 through Visual Studio 2012 but keep getting an error 25 connection string is not valid message when trying to connect through server explorer.

I am not connected to the domain but have checked that remote connections are enabled and port 1433. I can also connect to the main server via remote desktop app.

I am new to SQL Server so any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks

I posted the question on stack overflow a while ago where I added a picture: [SQL Server 2012 connection issues in Visual Studio 2012 Server Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112497/sql-server-2012-connection-issues-in-visual-studio-2012-server-explorer)

Comment: Part of the Stackexchange mentality is to not cross post questions. This question is also off topic, but voting to close as off topic will move it to that other question.

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem is not giving the database instance name in addition to the server name when trying to connect to a SQL Express installation. With other editions you can provide just the server name.

[image]